# How can we get last created field in graphQL create mutation call response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

Here is my mutation class definition that I am using for creating fields. For update I am using another class which gives me updated custom field only which is also described below.

This is for create mutation.

```
import Relay from "react-relay";

class CustomFieldCreateMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   getMutation() {
      return Relay.QL `
                mutation customField { createField }
            `;
   }

   getVariables() {
      return {
         customFieldDefinition: {
            name: this.props.customFieldName,
            schema: {
               type: this.props.customFieldType,
               format: this.props.customFieldFormat,
               title: this.props.title,
               allowedOperations: this.props.allowedOperations,
               allowedValues: this.props.allowedValues
            },
            associatedEntityTypes: this.props.associatedEntityTypes
         }
      };
   }

   getFatQuery() {
      return Relay.QL `
                fragment on CreateCommon_CustomFieldDefinitionPayload {
                    customFieldEdge,
                    company{
                        customFields
                    }
                  }
            `;
   }

   getConfigs() {
      return [{
         type: "RANGE_ADD",
         parentName: "company",
         parentID: this.props.company.id,
         connectionName: "createField",
         edgeName: "customFieldEdge",
         rangeBehaviors: {
            "": "append"
         }
      }];
   }
}

export default CustomFieldCreateMutation;

//// This is for update mutation class.

import Relay from "react-relay";

class CustomFieldUpdateMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   getMutation() {
      return Relay.QL `
            mutation customField { updateField }
        `;
   }

   getVariables() {
      return {
         commonCustomFieldDefinition: {
            id: this.props.customFieldId,
            name: this.props.customFieldName,
            deleted: !this.props.isActive,
            schema: {
               type: this.props.customFieldType,
               title: this.props.title,
               format: this.props.customFieldFormat,
               allowedOperations: this.props.allowedOperations,
               allowedValues: this.props.allowedValues
            },
            associatedEntityTypes: this.props.associatedEntityTypes
         }
      };
   }

   getFatQuery() {
      return Relay.QL `
            fragment on UpdateCommon_CustomFieldDefinitionPayload {
                customField
              }
        `;
   }

   getConfigs() {
      return [{
         type: "FIELDS_CHANGE",
         fieldIDs: {
            customField: this.props.customFieldId
         }
      }];
   }
}

export default CustomFieldUpdateMutation;
```

Comment: What is not working with the example you gave us?

Comment: So I am trying to get last created field in response which I am not getting. Can I get some newly created field by mutation id?

Comment: No you can't, in fact you can't "create field", your schema is static